# Solving a nonlinear equation maybe with Lambert W function

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, special-functions, polylogarithms

Can you please help me solve the following nonlinear equation?

\begin{equation}
     \boldsymbol{z} \odot\left(\boldsymbol{\Gamma}^{\top} \boldsymbol{y}\right)=(\beta)^{\frac{1}{m-1}}\left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right)^{\frac{m}{m-1}}\left(-\frac{m}{m-1}\right)
    \left(\boldsymbol{1}^{\top}\left(-\alpha\varepsilon \ln (\boldsymbol{z})-\boldsymbol{\nu}\right)^{m}\right)^{\frac{2-m}{m-1}}  \left(-\alpha\varepsilon \ln (\boldsymbol{z})-\boldsymbol{\nu}\right)^{m-1}.\label{33b}
\end{equation}

All the parameters ($\boldsymbol{\Gamma}$, $y$, $\beta$, $m$, $\boldsymbol{\nu}$, $\alpha$, and $\varepsilon$) are given, and I want to solve this equation for $\boldsymbol{z}$.

For the case that $m=2$, I can use the Lambert W function and solve it but I am wondering if there is a general solution for general $m$.

Comment: What is $\odot$?

Comment: The symbol $\odot$ denotes the elementwise multiplication.